# Automate login to secure website in java?

Tags: java, authentication, automation, httpclient

As part of a small project i'm doing that will never actually go into 'production' I need to be able to log into a very secure website and retrieve html.

I've been looking into doing this using the apache commons HTTPCLient. However i just wanted to make sure it was even possible as this website is very secure and likely has sso methods to sign in?
If it is possible, what is the best way to do this? I need to be able to navigate through about three pages once i have logged in so will need to store the cookie or session somehow.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, its possible to do this using apache http components, but for interacting with complex websites nothing (that i know) beats [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). to work with httpcomponents you'd need to "script" the whole sequence of http requests, and you'll have a problem if anything in the middle relies on dynamic content/javascript.

HtmlUnit, on the other hand, is an almost complete "bowser in a box" and you can script the interaction at a much higher level - click this, fill those values, submit etc.

Answer (score -1):

You need jsoup.jar file to send the response to the particular website
look at the gmail form data through inspect element for element verfication

```
 package com.kowthal;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HttpUrlConnectionExample {

  private List<String> cookies;
  private HttpsURLConnection conn;

  private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth";
    String gmail = "https://mail.google.com/mail/";

    HttpUrlConnectionExample http = new HttpUrlConnectionExample();

    // make sure cookies is turn on
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

    // 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
    String page = http.GetPageContent(url);
    String postParams = http.getFormParams(page, "username@gmail.com", "password");

    // 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
    // authentication
    http.sendPost(url, postParams);

    // 3. success then go to gmail.
    String result = http.GetPageContent(gmail);
    System.out.println(result);
  }

  private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // Acts like a browser
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "accounts.google.com");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    // Send post request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = 
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    // System.out.println(response.toString());

  }

  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // default is GET
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    // act like a browser
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }
    }
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // Get the response cookies
    setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

    return response.toString();

  }

  public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    // Google form id
    Element loginform = doc.getElementById("gaia_loginform");
    Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
    List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
        String key = inputElement.attr("name");
        String value = inputElement.attr("value");

        if (key.equals("Email"))
            value = username;
        else if (key.equals("Passwd"))
            value = password;
        paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
    }

    // build parameters list
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String param : paramList) {
        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result.append(param);
        } else {
            result.append("&" + param);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  public List<String> getCookies() {
    return cookies;
  }

  public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
    this.cookies = cookies;
  }

}
```